# How to create a Cookie using SSL pages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, cookies, ssl, https

I have an ASP:NET MVC 2 web site that is on SSL. I want to create a cookie like this:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(validatedUser.UserName, false);
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, validatedUser.SecureToken, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10), false, String.Empty);

HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket));
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

But I get an exception, telling: "**The application is configured to issue secure cookies. These cookies require the browser to issue the request over SSL (https protocol). However, the current request is not over SSL.**"

In web.config I have:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LoginError" timeout="2880" requireSSL="true" protection="All"/>
</authentication>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Has someone been reading this? http://codebutler.com/firesheep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requireSSL="false"` or use `http://` to request your site. Note that both are bad idea if you care about security. If you want a secure site leave `requireSSL="true"` and use `https://` to request your site.

Also the [SetAuthCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie.aspx) method already writes the cookie to the response so you don't need the rest:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(validatedUser.UserName, false);
```

is enough. You don't need to worry about `FormsAuthenticationTicket` and adding the cookie to the response.

Comment: I have    requireSSL="true" and use    https:// because I need security, but I always get that exception.

Comment: Well, the exception you are getting proves that you are not using `https://`. Or maybe there's some firewall or proxy server between the client and the web server which rewrites the request? Is the SSL certificate installed on the web server?

Comment: I found the problem. It is that when I run the web site form VisualStudio it wont work. If I run the site over IIS, it works.

Comment: I have the opposite problem.  Mine works from VS (IIS Express or local IIS 7) but doesn't work from AppHarbor.  If RequireSSL = false, then I can use AppHarbor's certificate and SSL works fine.  When I look at the traffic through Fiddler, I cannot see any place where the browser is trying to transmit the cookie without SSL (HTTPS).